# html5 video tag JSF2

Tags: jsf, html, jsf-2

I have in my code

```
<video id="myVideo" width="100%"  controls="controls">
   <source src="C:\\myVid.ogg"  type='video/ogg; codecs=&quot;theora, vorbis&quot;' />
  </video>
```

Is there away to use it in JSF2 (dynamic source)

EDITED:

I am trying to link to file on the disc of another server:

```
<video id="myVideo" width="100%"  controls="controls">
<source src="\\myip\storage\ogg\VX-276.ogg"  type='video/ogg; codecs=&quot;theora, vorbis&quot;' />
</video>
```

(the source is actually EL experssion).
the file is not being displayed!

When I try to open it with chrome it automatically changes it to: `file://myip/storage/ogg/VX-276.ogg` I tried to add in my servlet image path `file:////myip//storage//ogg//VX-276.ogg` however the url is changes to `file:\myip\storage\ogg\VX-276.ogg` which does not exist!

if I write `\\\\myip\\storage\\ogg\\VX-276.ogg` the file is found by not being displayed in the browser!

How do I need to write the URL to display it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Facelets, you can just use EL in template text.

```
<video id="myVideo" width="100%" controls="controls">
    <source src="#{bean.videoURL}" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I use something similar to http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html for video URL out of application scope? I tried the same servlet - but it doesn't reach the doGet method

Comment: Then the URL is plain wrong or the servlet is not mapped at all.

Comment: The url is "/image/VX-381.ogg" and I have image on the same page: <h:graphicImage value="/image/bat.bmp" /> where it works for it but not for the video (it reaches in breakpoint just for the image)

Comment: You need to remove the leading slash or to prefix with context path yourself like `"#{request.contextPath}/image/VX-381.ogg"` or to set the HTML `<base>` tag in head. The `<h:graphicImage>` prepends the URL automatically with the context path.

Comment: now it reaches the doGet method and it looks good,
but at the element source  it shows  "http://localhost:8080/myProgName/image/VX-381.ogg" instead of  "C:\VX-381.ogg"

Comment: Do all your website visitors have this file on their local disk? I don't think so :)

Comment: You still don't understand it? The last comment was sarcastic. HTML is been executed in webbrowser, not in webserver. Wherever the HTML is been executed, any local disk file system reference like "C:\VX-381.ogg" **must** be present in the same machine as where the HTML is been executed. This ain't going to work when the webbrowser runs at a physically different machine than the webserver. It has to be an URL so that the webbrowser can download the desired file from the webserver. As you now have with a servlet it's perfectly fine.

Comment: So the location needs to be http://linktomyip/sharedFolder/VS-381.ogg? the access is only for users inside our intranet so only those who have access to linktomyip will see it

Comment: The location doesn't matter, as long as it is an *URL* which is reachable for all your visitors and **not** a *local disk file system path* which is only reachable for yourself.

Comment: I tried it.Again I set the this.imagePath = "\\\\myip\\storage\\ogg\\"; which could be reach in the intranet, and the video source with <source src="#{request.contextPath}/image/VX-276.ogg"  type='video/ogg; codecs=&quot;theora, vorbis&quot;' /> however I see in chrome insepector that the link is http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/image/VX-276.ogg instead of  \\myip\storage\ogg\VX-276.ogg

Comment: Again, it has to be an URL. Let it point to your servlet and let your servlet read it from myip/storage or whatever and write it to response. That's all. Your servlet is the only who can access myip/storage. As you now have with `http://localhost:8080/myProgName/image/VX-381.ogg` it's perfectly fine.

Comment: it reaches my servlet, and there is a video in the line File video= new File(imagePath, URLDecoder.decode(requestedImage, "UTF-8"));  could it be problem with the rest parameters? response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
        response.setContentType(contentType);
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(video.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + video.getName() + "\"");? the contentType is "application/ogg" since it does not play it in the video tag

Comment: What exactly is the problem which you have now right now? I'm totally lost. I understood that it is all working fine, right? You said that the servlet is hit and that it looks good, but then you started to complain that the URL shouldn't have been an URL for some unobvious reason.

Comment: I am saying that it reaches the servlet, however the video is now being displayed on the screen! everthough the file exists on the other computer

Comment: Uh, have you been deflowered with regard to web development? Congratulations and welcome to the wonderful world of web development.

Comment: Ah, you mean to say "not" instead of "now" in the last comment? Well, then likely the `File` inside your servlet code is been created with an incorrect path. This is not a problem with the URL. It's perfectly fine. You should not try to make the URL more worse. The servlet runs, that's where it is all about. You only need to fix the `File` in the servlet code so that it points to a valid location. If you stucks, you should actually be asking a new question since that's completely offtopic to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You tried something like this?

```
<video width="300" height="200" controlis="controls">
<source src="movie.ogg"  type="video/ogg">
<source src="movie.mp4"  type="video/mpeg">
Your browser don't support video element.
</video>
```

...

```
var video = document.createElement('video');
video.src = 'video.ogg';
video.controls = true;
document.body.appendChild(video);
```

...

```
<cc.implementation>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="video.js" target="head"/>
<video src="#{cc.attrs.src}" controls="#{cc.attrs.controls}"></video>
</cc.implementation>
```

It`s should work, create dinamically audio and video.