# Locating a file in a network disk in a Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, file-io

I create ImageServlet to refer to videos out of my web application scope.

The location of all of my videos are on a intranet location that could be reached from any computer in the intranet:

```
String path = "\\myip\storage\ogg\VX-276.ogg"
```

In my application, when I write it as URL  - it can't display it!

If I try to open it with chrome it automatically changes it to `file://myip/storage/ogg/VX-276.ogg` and the file is being displayed.

I tried to do so: `file:////odelyay_test64/storage/ogg/`
as well but Java converts the string to: `file:\myip\storage\ogg\VX-276.ogg` which does not exist!

What is the correct way to refer to it?

**EDITED**

I create a small test:

```
String path = "file://myip/storage/ogg/VX-276.ogg";
        File file = new File(path);
        if (file.exists())
            System.out.println("exists");
        else {
            System.out.println("missing" + file.getPath());
        }
```

and I get:

```
missing file:\myip\storage\ogg\VX-276.ogg
```

As you can see the slashes are being switched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the end I used VFS library of apache and my code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileSystemManager fsManager = null;
        String path = "\\\\myip\\storage\\ogg\\VX-276.ogg";
        try {
             fsManager = VFS.getManager();

        FileObject basePath;


            basePath = fsManager.resolveFile("file:" + path);




            if (basePath.exists())
                System.out.println("exists");
            else {
                System.out.println("missing" + basePath.getURL());
            }
        } catch (FileSystemException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In this way, I don't need to create a driver for each user of the system and it allows me not to depend on operation system!

Answer (score 3):

As per your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231817/html5-video-tag-jsf2), you're referencing the resource in a HTML `<video>` tag. All URLs in the HTML source code **must** be `http://` URLs (or at least be relative to a `http://` URL). Most browsers namely refuse to load resources from `file://` URLs when the HTML page is itself been requested by `http://`. You just need to let the URL point to the servlet. If the servlet's `doGet()` method get hit, then the URL is fine and you should not change it.

Your concrete problem is in the way how you open and read the desired file in the servlet. You need to ensure that the `path` in `File file = new File(path)` points to a valid location before you open a `FileInputStream` on it.

```
String path = "file://myip/storage/ogg/VX-276.ogg";
File file = new File(path);
// ...
```

If the servlet code is well written that it doesn't suppress/swallow exceptions and you have read the server logs, then you should have seen an `IOException` such as `FileNotFoundException` along with a self-explaining message in the server logs whenever reading the file fails. Go read the server logs.

---

**Update** as per the comments, it turns out that you're using Windows and thus `file://` on a network disk isn't going to work for Java without mapping it on a drive letter. You need to map `//myip` on a drive letter first, for example `X:`.

```
String path = "X:/storage/ogg/VX-276.ogg";
File file = new File(path);
// ...
```

Comment: I tried that.But it returns 404 - file not found. when I debug it I see that in the 'path' variable it's file:\myip\storage\ogg\VX-276.ogg which truely does not exist only file://myip/storage/ogg/VX-276.ogg. Java somehow changes it

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux? Does Java have the permission to access the network drive? Forget about JSF, Servlet and HTML and all. They are not the cause of this problem. Just create a basic Java class with a `main()` method to test `new File(path)` and so on. It's quicker with testing.

Comment: Sigh. Windows or Linux? I'll assume Windows since it is known to malform the path like that. In that case you need to map the drive on a letter. Like `X:/storage/ogg/VX-276.ogg`.

Comment: windows. The other server is not mapped as a letter - so you mean that I have to map it as a driver and then to use it?